# Encontrar una palabra en un texto

Tags: python-2.7, txt

estoy haciendo un código que me dice si después de meter un texto.txt y un a palabra por teclado, me diga que la palabra se encuentra o no, aunque lo creía muy fácil, siempre me dice que la palabra no está aunque en realidad sí esté, yo he puesto lo siguiente

```
fichero=open(raw_input('Introduce el nombre del fichero: '),'r')
palabra_elegida=raw_input('Introduce el nombre de la palabra: ')
for palabra in fichero:
    if palabra==palabra_elegida:
        print 'la palabra esta'
    else:
        print 'la palabra no esta'

fichero.close()
```

Y el texto es este

Unas horas despues de que Donald Trump y Joe
Biden se enfrentaran en Cleveland en un tosco
primer debate lleno de gritos y descalificaciones
personales, al otro lado del Pacifico dos mujeres
mas jovenes protagonizaron otro debate presidencial mucho
mas afable y civilizado que el de Estados Unidos

Si alguien me puede echar una mano y me dice porque siempre me da como resultado una vez que he corrido el código que la palabra no está, aunque la que ponga, sé de forma cierta que está en el texto, se lo agradecería. Saludos

Comment: Más abajo tienes las respuestas, pero quisiera añadir que aunque Python 2.x es un buen lenguaje, esta llegando a un desuso, por lo que te recomiendo que te cambies a Python 3.x.
Saludos ;)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo valido si una cadena está dentro de otra?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395505/c%c3%b3mo-valido-si-una-cadena-est%c3%a1-dentro-de-otra)

Answer (score 3):

En tu código, `palabra` tiene una línea completa, por lo que la comparación falla.

En lugar de

```
if palabra==palabra_elegida:
```

usa

```
if palabra_elegida in palabra:
```

Ahi si funciona.

Comment: Correcto. Viendo que esta pregunta es recurrente, he publicado una con intención de canónica en [¿Cómo valido si una cadena está dentro de otra?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/395505/83) para que sea destino de duplicados en el futuro. La respuesta es wiki, por si quieres mejorarla.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Está perfecta. Nada que agregar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `fichero` representa el archivo de texto en cuestión, el primer `for` loop itera sobre cada línea del archivo, **no** sobre cada palabra.

Si quieres iterar sobre cada palabra, hay que "partir" la línea por cada palabra que exista en cada línea con el método [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), y luego iterar sobre la lista de palabras producida por el split:

```
fichero = open(raw_input('Introduce el nombre del fichero: '),'r')
palabra_elegida = raw_input('Introduce el nombre de la palabra: ')

found = False

for linea in fichero:
    for palabra in linea.split():
        if palabra == palabra_elegida:
            found = True
            break

if found:
    print 'La palabra esta'
else:
    print 'La palabra no esta'


fichero.close()
```

Alternativamente, como sugirió Candid Moe puedes usar `in` para revisar si la palabra está presente en cada línea:

```
for linea in fichero:
    if palabra_elegida in linea:
        found = True
        break
```

Nota: agregue un `break` para que el loop deje de iterar una vez encontrada la palabra.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una versión usando la librería de expresiones regulares **re**:

```py
import re
with open(input('Introduce el nombre del fichero: '), 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    word = input('Introduce el nombre de la palabra: ')
    print("La palabra {}{} se encuentra en el texto".format(word, "" if re.search(word, text, re.IGNORECASE) else " no"))
```

Es compatible con *Python 2* si cambias *input* por *raw_input*.

Es recomendable abrir los ficheros mediante *with open*, ya que cierra los ficheros "automáticamente"; en caso de que ocurriera alguna excepción, se liberarían correctamente los recursos.

Si además quisieras que la palabra fuera *case-sensitive*, es decir, que se respetaran las mayúsculas y minúsculas, sólo debes eliminar el *flag re.IGNORECASE*.

Comment: Es excesivo usar expresiones regulares cuando puedes resolverlo con un simple `in`. Si el OP tiene problemas básicos con strings, las expresiones regulares no son una alternativa para él. Sigue participando.

Comment: Tienes razón, sólo era una sugerencia que no toma un par de líneas de código, gracias!