# ¿Cómo valido si una cadena está dentro de otra?

Tags: python, string, substring

A menudo me ocurre que quiero ver si una cadena está dentro de otra.

Por ejemplo, me gustaría saber si el texto "hola" está dentro de la cadena "se te saluda, pepito, hola" o en "hola don pepito".

¿Existe alguna función tipo `cadena.contains("bla")` para decir algo así como `"se te saluda, pepito, hola".contains("hola")`?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437059/1983854

Comment: Publico esta pregunta para intentar canonizarla y así evitar tenerla dispersa en muchas otras preguntas que lo abordan tangencialmente dentro de cosas más grandes que acaban siendo esto. La respuesta la he puesto en modo wiki para que la mejoremos entre todos (si bien poco margen hay) y que así se vea que no lo hago para la reputación :)

Comment: Por mi parte, jamás te cuestionaría que ganes reputación por esta pregunta, de hecho me parece que hasta sería adecuado que sea así.

Comment: De hecho yo varias veces lo he pensado que se debería de hacer, pero no sabía si era lo correcto en el sitio. Hay muchísimas preguntas de este tipo que siempre viene a ser lo mismo. Por ejemplo, en Python con Pandas siempre hay un par de preguntas todas las semanas que al final se resumen en "¿Cómo puedo juntar dos DataFrames?".  Estaría bien que hubiera solo una respuesta General a errores comunes, como por ejemplo este!

Comment: @RubialesAlberto adelante con ella! Yo creo que es buena práctica hacer este tipo de preguntas canónicas, pues permiten _preparar_ bien el enunciado para que cubra lo esencial y que luego la respuesta sea lo más completa posible. Muchas veces las preguntas concretas tienen detalles que hacen que sea complicado _canonizarlas_, por lo que hacer una adrede creo que ayuda. Y luego viene marcar el resto como duplicadas, así como documentarlo en la wiki de la etiqueta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma idiomática de hacerlo es utilizar el operador [`in`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

```
if 'subcadena' in cadena:
    #          ^^
    # ...
```

---

Si resulta que quieres saber *dónde* ocurre la subcadena dentro de la cadena, entonces puedes usar [`cadena.find(subcadena)`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

```
>>> 'hola'.find('X')
-1                    # no se encuentra
>>> 'hola'.find('l')
2                     # está en la posición 2 (empezando por 0)
```

Puedes usar también los parámetros `start` y `end` para indicar a partir de dónde (y hasta dónde) quieres buscar la cadena:

```
>>> 'holala'.find('a')
3
>>> 'holala'.find('a', 4)
5
```