# Comprobar si una palabra de una string coincide con otra

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero comprobar si el valor de la variable `a` coincide con el contenido de las dos `strings` que tengo. He pensado lo siguiente pero no me funciona ya que el output es `no`. Alguna idea?

```
newStr = 'FFN1'
actStr = 'FFN1'

a = 'FFN'

if newStr.find(str(a)) == actStr.find(str(a)):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("no")
```

Y en el caso de que en la string `actStr` el valor fuera `FFN2`, lo detectaría como igual teniendo en cuenta el valor de `a`?

Comment: ¿Qué significa "el valor de la variable `a` coincide con el contenido de las dos strings que tengo"? En tu caso no coincide exactamente, aunque sí comienzan de la misma forma. ¿Es eso lo que quieres verificar? ¿Que comienzan de la misma forma? ¿O que ambas contienen "FFN" como substring? Y si es esto, ¿ambas tienen que tener ese substring en la misma posición? (es lo que parece a la vista de lo que has puesto en el `if`) ¿O te valdría que una fuera por ejemplo "FFN1" y otra "XYZFFN1"?

Comment: Quiero comprobar que es valor es exactamente el mismo, pero yo nunca sabré si el valor es 1 o 92. Me serviría algo como `FFN*` para que me entiendas mejor.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo valido si una cadena está dentro de otra?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395505/c%c3%b3mo-valido-si-una-cadena-est%c3%a1-dentro-de-otra)

Comment: `if newStr.startswith(a) and actStr.startswith(a):` te sirve?

Comment: no porque no necesariamente esta en el inicio de la string

Comment: Entonces mi respuesta es la que soluciona tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes mantener simple con `any` puesto que lo único que necesitas es saber si **cualquiera** de las comparaciones no comienza con `a` ("FFN"). Tal como lo pides, esto funcionará con cualquier número sufijado en las variables:

```py
newStr = "FFN1"
actStr = "FFN1"
otra_2 = "FFN3"
otra_3 = "FFN23091203219902"

a = "FFN"

ffns = (newStr, actStr, otra_2, otra_3)

if not any(ffn.startswith(a) for ffn in ffns):
    print("Ninguna coincidencia")
else:
    print(f"Coinciden: {', '.join(ffns)}".replace(a, f"<<{a}>>"))
```

Resultado:

```
Coinciden: <<FFN>>1, <<FFN>>1, <<FFN>>3, <<FFN>>23091203219902
```

Comment: No me sirve ya que no quiero comprobar si empieza o no con esta string

Comment: @andyio Entonces reemplaza el `ffn.startswith(a)` por `a in ffn`.

Answer (score 1):

**str.find(sub[, start[, end]])**

> Retorna el menor índice de la cadena s donde se puede encontrar la
> cadena sub, considerando solo el intervalo s[start:end]. Los
> parámetros opcionales start y end se interpretan como si fueran
> “indices de una rebanada. retorna -1 si no se encuentra la cadena.

Si `actStr` fuera `FFN2` ... probemos:

```
newStr = 'FFN1'
actStr = 'FFN2'

a = 'FFN'

print(newStr.find(a))
print(actStr.find(a))
```

produce:

```
0
0
```

La respuesta es: SI. Ambas contiene la secuencia (y la tienen en la misma posición)

La función `find` te dice donde comienza la cadena que buscas. Por lo tanto, cualquier resultado igual o mayor que cero te dira que ambos newStr y actStr contienen la misma secuencia, aunque probablemente no en la misma posición.

Nota: `a` es un string; no necesitas convertirlo usando `str()`